# Stop responding to windows commands

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition

Please have a look at the following code

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();

            Choices colors = new Choices();
            colors.Add(new string[] { "red arrow", "green", "blue" });

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(colors);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

            sr.LoadGrammar(g);

           // SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
           // s.SpeakAsync("start speaking");

            sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);
        }

        void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
        }
```

This is normal speech recognition code which uses the MS speech engine. You can see here that I have loaded some grammar. But, there is an issue as well. That is, this is not responding only to the given grammar but also to the MS Built-In speech commands! Like speech command to minimize a window, open start menu etc!

I really don't need that. My application should only respond to my grammar and not to MS built-in commands. Is there is a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpeechRecognizer` object builds on top of the existing Windows Speech system. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.aspx):

> Applications use the shared recognizer to access Windows Speech
>   Recognition. Use the SpeechRecognizer object to add to the Windows
>   speech user experience.

Consider using a [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) object instead as this runs in-process rather than system-wide.

Comment: This is interesting. I will try this and let you know. :)